# How to save(download) HTML page with all images, css etc in Android?

Tags: android, html, css, save

I am developing Android application which is used to open pages from wiki resource. I want to save that pages to watch them later. So, is there a possibility to do it using libraries - write my own html-parser is a bit complicated for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `DefaultHttpClient` as the response will hold all the data.

Here's the basic syntax:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet('http://www.somedomain.com/somePath');

try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    // store the response afterwards
} catch ([…]) {
    […]
}
```

More information can be found here: [Android Developers | DefaultHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you just need HTML parser, here are some Open Source Java Parsers : [Java Parsers](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers)

You can also use [Html.fromHtml(source)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html);

I'm not sure whether it support all HTML tags, but it has a handler, that you can implement on unknown tags . . .

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way of doing it, you need to save html data and all resources image/css/scripts etc. and update there paths in  html data(for this you need html parser), **[similar question is answered here..](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9415274/1677824)**